# Drupal 7: mark as offensive flag

Tags: 7, flags

I want to create a 'mark as offensive' flag for my site. However, I have no idea how to go about it. Is there a tutorial on the web that will guide me through the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, checkout the [Flag Abuse](http://drupal.org/project/flag_abuse) module.

> It works by giving a new permission for a role to be able to reset flags. If a role has this permission, the flag is changed to say 'Reset' instead of whatever the default text may be. When that user clicks this it resets all of the abuse flags on that object and makes to that it cannot be flagged as abuse anymore.

Answer (score 3):

To do this you could use a popular module http://drupal.org/project/flag.
There is also documentation here http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag.

Comment: Some more screencasts are here http://nodeone.se/learn-flag-part-1

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5xieuVf01E&feature=BFa&list=PL1A89955CCEB73A09&lf=iv
short and to the point